# Shunting Yard Algorithm with Variables

Tags: math, shunting-yard, rewriting

I'm currently working on a modified version of the Shunting Yard Algorithm that would work with variables, but I cant figure out how to get it to work. For example, I would want the algorithm to re-write 2 * (2x + 5) - 5 to 4x + 5. Any ideas / links to already implemented algorithms that does this already?

Comment: That's too complex if you don't want to use a binary tree.

Comment: If I use a binary tree instead, how would I go to implement a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Take the expression: `2 * (2x + 5) - 5`
2. Add the * symbol to make it more understandable for the computer: `2 * (2*x + 5) - 5`
3. Parse it using the Shunting Yard Algorithm, it becomes: `2 2 x * 5 + * 5 -` (Each character could be seen as an element of an array).
4. With the parsed expression, create the binary tree:

`-
         /   \
        *     5
      /   \
     2     +
         /   \
        *     5
      /   \
     2     x`

5. Define and apply algebraic rules to the tree. For example, a rule to be able to 'multiply' the `2` node with the `2 * x + 5` subtree.

Comment: Feel free to ask if you need me to explain me more :)

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean. Would this approach work for functions as well?

Comment: With functions you mean trigonometric functions? I'm developing an online CAS with this approach and at the moment it can solve algebraic equations, limits, derivatives and a few integrals.

Comment: Functions such as trig functions, as well as log, ln, ect.

Comment: Yeah, with this model you can cover all of those. Trig functions, log, ln, etc. have just one child node (argument).

Comment: @gab06 Thanks. ;) - didn't want to seem chatty in the other question.