# Evaluating variable from postfix expression

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, postfix-notation, shunting-yard

I'm trying to build a solver for single variable equations. I'm using Shunting-yard algorithm, expanded with suggestions by [denver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29652095/3735245) and [rici](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16392115/3735245). Obviously this algorithm works great to parse trough given math expression, determine its validity and evaluate the value. However, I'm having trouble to understand how to incorporate solving for a certain variable.

If I use the equation `2 * (x - 4) = 4`, this can without much fuss be transformed into RPN as `2 x 4 - * 4 -`. From here, it would be easy to evaluate the value for any given `x`. But, how to determine `x`? I'm looking at [gab's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25320800/3735245) answer, and although it's clear to me how to build a tree from the RPN form, I don't understand how to calculate the value (step 5. in his answer).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You what you would do if you solved this with pencil and paper: You move stuff to the other side of the equation until only `x` remains. Your tree looks like this:

```
        =
      /   \
    *       4
   / \
  2   −
     / \
    x   4
```

All branches are operators, all leaves are operands. The path from your single variable passed through the `*` and `−` nodes on the left-hand side. That means that you must get as much stuff as possible from the left-hand side to the right-hand side, ideally until there is only the `x` node left.

The first node on the left is a multiplication operator. You can apply the transformation

```
a * b == c    ⟺    b = c / a
```

to the tree: Remove the multiplication on the left and insert its inverse operation, division by the constant 2, on the right. Your tree now looks like this:

```
        =
      /   \
    −       ÷
   / \     / \
  x   4   4   2
```

The division operates on two constants. You can "fold" them into the result, 2:

```
        =
      /   \
    −       2
   / \ 
  x   4
```

(If you have only one variable, you can do that as you create the nodes, so that you don't have an intermediary step with a `÷` node that you are going to delete anyway. You should also detect any divisions by zero here.)

Now move the subtraction operator in the same way:

```
        =
      /   \
    x       +
           / \
          2   4
```

Calculate the constant expression on the right and you get `x == 6`.

So you basically turn the top-most left-hand operator into its inverse until there's only the variable left:

```
a + x == b   ⟺   x == b − a            x + a == b   ⟺   x == b − a
a − x == b   ⟺   x == a − b            x − a == b   ⟺   x == b + a
a * x == b   ⟺   x == b / a            x * a == b   ⟺   x == b / a
a / x == b   ⟺   x == a / b            x / a == b   ⟺   x == b * a
```

If you have only one variable and have resolved all constant expressions, your `x` will be the variable or an operator node; the `a` will be a constant number.

(But careful with division: In the example above, the division has no remainder. If the division has a remainder, integer division will not give the correct result when resolving the value of `x` and floating-point division will likely introduce small errors.)